# Is this class thread safe: com.orionserver.http.OrionHttpJspPage

Tags: oracle, jsp, servlets, concurrency, oc4j

We use JDeveloper 10.1.3.4 to develop a web application. We deploy the application on OC4J running on linux. We put java code in the jsp page directly. In the jsp page, we have general java code, for example,

```
<% String invoice_id = ""; %>
```

Here the variable invoice_id is an instance variable in jsp. We also have tag such as  and  to handle database transactions. We have such a jsp called paymentApproved.jsp. This jsp is called by a third party gateway. In other words, the jsp is called from outside of our application. My question is, in such a scenario, is this jsp paymentApproved.jsp thread safe? I checked the translated jsp page, the class extends *com.orionserver.http.OrionHttpJspPage*, and the logic is in this method:

```
public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws java.io.IOException, ServletException
```

Specifically, I am not sure whether an instance variable defined in such a jsp is thread safe while multiple requests coming in to call the page? Or is there anyway to test it? (I know it's a bad idea to put java code in jsp. But it's my boss's project, not mine. )Thanks

Jsp code:

```
<%@ include file="mainHeader.jsp"%>
<%
  String inv_id = "";
%>

<jbo:ApplicationModule id="AM_Payment" definition="test.AM_Payment" releasemode="Stateless" />
<jbo:DataSource id="dsinv" appid="AM_Payment" viewobject="InvoiceView1"/>

<%

  SimpleDateFormat dtformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  SimpleDateFormat tmformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  String invoicedateStr = dtformat.format(new java.util.Date());
  oracle.jbo.domain.Date invoicedate = new oracle.jbo.domain.Date(invoicedateStr);
  String invoicetime = tmformat.format(new java.util.Date());

  inv_id = invoicedateStr+invoicetime;
```

%>

```
<BR><BR>
<table>
  <tr><td>Invoice id:&nbsp;&nbsp; <%=inv_id%></td></tr>
</table>
<hr>
<% 

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int[] dummy = new int[10];
      for (int i=0; i<999999999; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
          dummy[j] = i;
        }
      } 
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = endTime - startTime;
    double seconds = (double)Math.round( (duration/1000000000.0d) *100.0d)/100.0d;    
    String sec = Double.toString(seconds);    
%>
<table>
<tr><td>Invoice id:&nbsp;&nbsp; <%=inv_id%></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>

<tr><td>Process time:&nbsp;&nbsp; <%=sec%>&nbsp;&nbsp;seconds</td></tr>

</table>
<hr>

<jbo:ReleasePageResources releasemode="Stateless"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Leaf

Answer (score 0):

```
<% String invoice_id = ""; %>
```

> Here the variable invoice_id is an instance variable in jsp.

No, it's not. It's a local variable of the service method of the JSP.

> is this jsp paymentApproved.jsp thread safe?

How coud we tell without seeing a single character of this JSP?

Putting Java code in a JSP is an extremely bad idea. Scriptlets shouldn't be used, for years and years. Use JSPs as pure view components, whose only role is to generate HTML markup from beans stored in te request by a controller written in Java.